# make autoplay work on IPAD and IPHONE

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video

I have fullscreen video background, here is my code:

```
<div id="video-container">
        <video id="video" autoplay loop>
            <source src="ocean.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="ocean.ogv" type="video/ogg">
            <source src="ocean.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
</div>
```

how you see it has autoplay attrubute, but on IPAD, IPHONE,etc.. it doesn't work untill you click on play button, but when I add poster attribute for poster image it works:

```
<video id="video" poster="poster.jpg" autoplay loop>
```

But I don't want with poster. Also I tried to use this js code but no result:

```
function startVideo(){ 
        var myVideo = document.getElementById('video'); 
        if ((myVideo.playing) || (myVideo.currentTime > 0)) { 
                // video is already playing 
        } else { 
                myVideo.play(); 
        } 
}   
window.document.body.onload = startVideo;
```

Comment: So how have you handled your problem scenario?

Comment: autoplay doesn't work on IPAD,IPHONE, but I have done it with poster image. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess auto-play feature is not supported in iOS. Check this Apple documentation:

> User Control of Downloads Over Cellular Networks
>
> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled.

Here is the documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4)